# Image in div is not show in Chrome but shows in IE

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have the following simple HTML code, the code runs correctly using the run snippet and in Internet Explorer.  However, if I copy this code, save it to text.html and try to run it in Chrome the image doesn't appear.

What is the nature of this problem?  And, how do I fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<H1>This is Scott!</H1>
<div>
  <img src='http://mgecombanners.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/5KAWFvr_JanTV18_Red_728x90.jpg' border='0' />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have checked both in chrome and IE, please check if you are having any other issue and check your console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have AdBlocker enabled it's blocking the image probably as it contains word "banner". Image displays as intended on incognito window.

Comment: Ah... that's a great thought.

Comment: Wow..... Yep, that was it.  I am somewhat kicking myself.  I'm doing some website development for myself and I am wondering why my ads aren't coming through.  Well.... duh.... I am using an AdBlocker.  Thanks man!

Comment: Awesome! Same thing happened to me a couple times, too. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

On an `https` website contents from an `http` website will not be loaded in all browsers, which is the case here (in the snippet on SO at least). (might also depend on personal browser settings)

Comment: That will not stop loading the content(in this case image), though you'll get a warning in console *"Mixed Content"*